# Display 2d array in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have created new column against every new value of N now it displays only the last column of every row also the column name is started from '0' I want to start it from '1'

```
private void printBoard(int[,] board,int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
          DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();              
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (i > 0 || j > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.ColumnCount = N;
                row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);                  
                dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name = j.ToString();
                    row.Cells[j].Value = board[i, j];
            }
        }
       this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image: display 2d array in DataGridView]

Comment: While you can show a 2d array manually in DataGridView, but it's better to use a DataTable to have data-binding. Also you don't need to pass `N` to the method, it should be the upper bound of 2nd dimention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify `N` as parameter of the method. You should get the number of columns and rows from bounds of the array using [`GetUpperBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method.

I changed the signature of the method a bit, to pass the `DataGridView` and the data:

```
private void printBoard(DataGridView dgv, int[,] board)
{
    var columns = board.GetUpperBound(1) + 1; //Number of columns
    var rows = board.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;    //Number of rows

    //Add columns (name, text)
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
    {
        dgv.Columns.Add($"{c + 1}", $"{c + 1}"); 
    }
    //Add rows
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        //Slice 2d array and get the row
        var row = Enumerable.Range(0, columns).Select(c => (object)board[r, c]).ToArray();
        //Add the row
        dgv.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

And here is an example of the usage:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var a = new int[,] { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2 }, { 3, 3, 3 }, { 4, 4, 4 } };
    printBoard(dataGridView1, a);
}
```

**Note:** In general, it's better to use data-binding when it's possible. For example if instead of a 2d array, you set a `DataTable` as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`, then when you edit the cells, the changes will be applied on the `DataTable`, however for the 2d array, you need to export data again into a 2d array manually.

Comment: well it worked aswell but its bit complicated so i went with other solution .. still thanks for early response :)

Comment: No worries, The choice is yours :) In fact in this answer I tried to show a few points, the way that you can add columns and set their text, the way that you can add rows 
 by passing an array to `Rows.Add`, and the way that you can slice a 2d array to rows.

Comment: BTW, JFYI, you can upvote useful answers including the accepted one by clicking on up arrow near the answer. To learn more, take a [tour].

Comment: i have done that sorry for the late response i was bit off

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863686/compare-the-selected-item-of-combobox-in-list-in-c-sharp  here im stuck in a problem aswell can you help me out

Answer (score 1):

Initialize columns and rows before filling board cells:

```
private void printBoard(int[,] board, int N)
{
    // create columns
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = N;
    for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)
        dataGridView1.Columns[c].Name = c.ToString();

    // create N empty rows
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(N);

    // fill cells
    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++)
        {              
            dataGridView1[c, r].Value = board[r, c];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863686/compare-the-selected-item-of-combobox-in-list-in-c-sharp                                                                                                 can you help me over this problem please i shall be thankful