# compare the items in list in c#

Tags: c#, list, combobox

i want to compare the selecteditem of combobox with the selecteditem of other combobox
for this i have registered all the comboboxes in a list and named it "panel1kilist"
now the problem i am facing is that when there are same items in two comboboxes first the messagebox shows "no mattch found" and then it shows "match found" actually it goes to the else statement of inner loop first and then to if statement kindly help

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool check = false;
            bool check1 = false;[![in this image you can see that there are two same items but message is showing "no match found"][1]][1]
            try[![after clicking on ok button of message box showing "no match found" this message box shows up][1]][1]
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < panel1kilist.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < panel1kilist.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (panel1kilist[i].SelectedItem.ToString() == panel1kilist[j].SelectedItem.ToString())
                        {
                            if (check == false)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("match found");
                            }
                            check = true;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            if (check1 == false)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("no match found");
                            }
                            check1 = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please fill all the boxes first");
            }


        }
```

Comment: can you please explain what is working and what is not working

Comment: output is false in same items as well as different items

Comment: label1.Text = "nomatch";  this statement is running only even in same values in two comboboxes

Comment: `myList.Distinct().Count() != myList.Count();` here you are checking again same list `mylist`

Comment: krishna is there any way to compare the items of comboboxes in a list ... comparison should be between the selected item (that is string in my case) of the combox

Comment: can you give us an example data and expected result. with the current information, it is very hard to give a solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206459/discussion-between-shahzeb-khan-and-krishna-muppalla).

Comment: It's not quite clear what the question is. Please edit the question, and explain about what you are trying to achieve, what is the user scenario and what is the expected result. What `HasSameData<T>(List<T> myList)` is expected to do, where/how the data of `myList` coming from. Please edit the question rather that answering the comments :)

Comment: i have edited code and tried my best to explain my question kindly look over it now

Comment: Just a small thing I recognized: In case the if-condition returns "false" within the first run, the else path will get executed and we see the Message "Match not found". As you set check1 = true it will always be true and you will never see the "Match not found" again because you check if check1 is false. And basically the same for your check variable. When the if conditions returns "true" you show the messag "Match found" and set the check variable to true. From now on its always true.

Comment: And you define i = 1 which skips the very first item in your list?/array? which starts at index 0

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet where we see the type of the list panel1kilist? So you must have something like List<?> panel1kilist = new List<?>(); And please add the code that defines the class you use as type for the List.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear but I still try to give you some help. As mentioned in the comments there are several small issues in your code:

**1. The outter for-loop**

```
for (int i = 1; i < panel1kilist.Count; i++)
```

You define i = 1, which means you skip the very first item in your panel1kilist because lists and arrays start at index 0

**2. Use of your bool variables**

```
if (panel1kilist[i].SelectedItem.ToString() == panel1kilist[j].SelectedItem.ToString())
{
     if (check == false)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("match found");
     }
     check = true;
}
else
{
     if (check1 == false)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("no match found");
     }
     check1 = true;
}
```

You define your bool variables before starting your for-loops. So whenever you set your variables check and check1 to true, the if conditions check == false and check1 == false will never return true anymore. So you will never get any message except the very first "Match found" and "no match found".

**3. My proposed solution**

Make use of the foreach-loop and break the loops once you found a match, after the loops just show the message. Code:

```
var matchFound = false;

foreach (var combobox in panel1kilist)
{
     foreach (var comboboxToMatch in panel1kilist.Skip(1))
     {
          if (combobox.SelectedItem.ToString() == comboboxToMatch.SelectedItem.ToString())
          {
               matchFound = true;
               // Stops the inner loop in case of a match
               break;
          }
     }

     // Stops the outer loop in case of a match
     if(matchFound)
     {
          break;
     }
}

if(matchFound)
{
     MessageBox.Show("match found");
}
```

Comment: Issue is same when i start with i = 0, secondly bool variables are used for showing message boxes one time if i dont use bool checks messagebox is showing 81 times and i have used your foreach loop code as well it gives the output "no match found" once and "match found" in each selection of item in combobox even if there are matching items or no matching items:

Comment: So you  want to show the message "Match found" exactly one time or every time you find a match?

Comment: exactly...!! any single match in all comboxes and it should display match found once only same case with distinct matches .. no match found should be displayed in that case

Comment: I updated my answer and code. Please have a look on the third part "3. My proposed solution" and check if this fixes your problem. Btw: You could also just put the MessageBox.Show() into the if condition where we check for SelectedItem equality and remove the last if-condition after the loops. I just wanted to show you how you can make use of your bool indicators